# Aplicando Carrera de Hilos en una interfaz ( no se refresca)

Tags: java, hilos, jframe

Explico rápidamente lo que pretendo, tengo dos corredores que ejecutan hilos simulando correr ( sumatoria de valor random), es un hilo lo que ejecuta y debe por cada iteracion del bucle en el hilo hacer un setvalue(distanciarecorridaenesemomento) en los `progressbar` de la interfaz.

Creo que mi problema esta en que no refresca el `jframe` y no se ven los cambios en los 2 `progressbar`

**Clase Corredor:**

```
    /*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package carrerahilos_con_interfaz;

import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 *
 * @author Josel
 */
public class Corredor extends Thread {

    private String nombre;
    private int distancia_recorrida;

    public Corredor(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.distancia_recorrida = 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        while (true) {
            mostrarDistanciaRecorridaActual();
            this.distancia_recorrida += avanzar();
            try {
                sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                System.out.println("Error Sleep Metho Corredor.run()");
            }

        }

    }

    public int avanzar() {
        int distancia_avanzada = 0;

        distancia_avanzada = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * (10 - 1 + 1) + 1);  // Valor entre M y N, ambos incluidos.

        return distancia_avanzada;
    }

    public void mostrarDistanciaRecorridaActual() {
        System.out.println("[" + this.nombre + "]Distancia recorrida: " + getDistanciaRecorrida());
    }

    public int getDistanciaRecorrida() {
        return this.distancia_recorrida;
    }

}
```

**Clase Interfaz:**

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package carrerahilos_con_interfaz;

/**
 *
 * @author Josel
 */
public class interfaz extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    private Corredor c1 = new Corredor("Ernesto");
    private Corredor c2 = new Corredor("Jesus");

    public interfaz() {
        initComponents();
        setVisible(true);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);


        pb_c1.setMaximum(100);
        pb_c2.setMaximum(100);
        pb_c1.setValue(0);
        pb_c2.setValue(0);
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jSlider1 = new javax.swing.JSlider();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        btn_empezarCarrera = new javax.swing.JButton();
        pb_c1 = new javax.swing.JProgressBar();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        pb_c2 = new javax.swing.JProgressBar();

        jButton1.setText("Salir");

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        btn_empezarCarrera.setBackground(java.awt.Color.green);
        btn_empezarCarrera.setText("Empezar Carrera");
        btn_empezarCarrera.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btn_empezarCarreraActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel1.setText("Corredor 1");

        jLabel2.setText("Corredor 2");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(btn_empezarCarrera, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 149, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap())
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jLabel1)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 19, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(pb_c1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 277, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(42, 42, 42))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jLabel2)
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addComponent(pb_c2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 277, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(btn_empezarCarrera, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 39, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(40, 40, 40)
                        .addComponent(pb_c1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 31, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(49, 49, 49)
                        .addComponent(jLabel1)))
                .addGap(44, 44, 44)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(pb_c2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 31, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(9, 9, 9)
                        .addComponent(jLabel2)))
                .addContainerGap(104, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        
public int avanzar() {
        int distancia_avanzada = 0;

        distancia_avanzada = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * (10 - 1 + 1) + 1);  // Valor entre M y N, ambos incluidos.

        return distancia_avanzada;
    }
    private void btn_empezarCarreraActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                   

        c1.start();
        c2.start();

        while (true) {            
            //pb_c1.setValue(c1.getDistanciaRecorrida());
            pb_c1.setValue(c1.getDistanciaRecorrida());
            pb_c2.setValue(c2.getDistanciaRecorrida());
           // revalidate(); no funciona
            //repaint(); no funciona
        }

    }                                                  

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(interfaz.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(interfaz.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(interfaz.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(interfaz.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new interfaz().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton btn_empezarCarrera;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JSlider jSlider1;
    private javax.swing.JProgressBar pb_c1;
    private javax.swing.JProgressBar pb_c2;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

**Clase main:**

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package carrerahilos_con_interfaz;

/**
 *
 * @author Josel
 */
public class CarreraHilos_con_interfaz {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {


        interfaz i = new interfaz();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Lo que te ocurre es que bloqueas el hilo principal con este ciclo infinito, por lo que la interfaz se bloquea también:

```
    while (true) {            
        //pb_c1.setValue(c1.getDistanciaRecorrida());
        pb_c1.setValue(c1.getDistanciaRecorrida());
        pb_c2.setValue(c2.getDistanciaRecorrida());
        // revalidate(); no funciona
        //repaint(); no funciona
    }
```

En vez de hacer eso, pásale el `JProgressBar` del corredor X a su hilo correspondiente, y actualiza su estado (valor) dentro del hilo. Para lograrlo debes realizar varios cambios.

1 - Modifica la implementación de la clase `Corredor` para que le puedas pasar el `JProgreeBar` y que el valor de este se actualice cada vez que se actualice la distancia recorrida.

```
class Corredor extends Thread {

    private String nombre;
    private int distancia_recorrida;
    private javax.swing.JProgressBar progressBar;// NUEVO

    public Corredor(String nombre, javax.swing.JProgressBar progressBar) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.progressBar = progressBar;// NUEVO. Deberías validar que no sea null
        this.distancia_recorrida = 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        while (true) {
            mostrarDistanciaRecorridaActual();
            this.distancia_recorrida += avanzar();
            progressBar.setValue(distancia_recorrida);// NUEVO
            try {
                sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                System.out.println("Error Sleep Metho Corredor.run()");
            }

        }

    }

    // Resto de métodos omitidos    
}
```

2 - Cambiar en la clase `interfaz` el modo de instanciar los atributos `c1` y `c2`, correspondientes a los corredores, para que le puedas pasar el `JProgressBar` ya creado. Debes hacer esto en el constructor de la clase.

```
class interfaz extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    private Corredor c1;// NUEVO
    private Corredor c2;// NUEVO

    public interfaz() {
        initComponents();
        setVisible(true);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        pb_c1.setMaximum(100);
        pb_c2.setMaximum(100);
        pb_c1.setValue(0);
        pb_c2.setValue(0);

        c1 = new Corredor("Ernesto", pb_c1);// NUEVO
        c2 = new Corredor("Jesus", pb_c2);// NUEVO
    }

    // Resto del código omitido
}
```

3 - Por último eliminar el ciclo `while` infinito, y problemático, del código del método `btn_empezarCarreraActionPerformed()` de la clase `interfaz`.

```
private void btn_empezarCarreraActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    c1.start();
    c2.start();
}
```

> **Nota:** Fíjate que las líneas donde aparece el comentario `// NUEVO` han sido modificadas o agregadas nuevas.

Comment: Considerar usar `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Runnable)` para actualizar el `ProgressBar` desde un *thread* distinto al *Event Dispatch Thread*